# working out an average of the values in a dictionary

Tags: python, math, average

My dictionary as of now is like this:

```
class_1 = {'Bob':[9,5,4,3,3,4], 'John':[5,5,7,3,6], 'Andy':[7,5,6,4,5], 'Harris':[3,4,2,3,2,3,2]}
```

What i am trying to make it look like is this:

```
class_1_average ={'Bob':[average of scores],'John':[average of scores].........
```

How can i do this so that even when the scores updates the average also updates with it. And is there also a way to find the highest score out of the scores

Comment: python3 if that helps

Comment: The downvotes here remind me the "Soup nazi" episode ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try like this:

```
class_1_average = {key: sum(value)/len(value) for key, value in class_1.items()}
```

For max value: you can use max built-in function over the value  of dictionary

```
max_each = {key: max(value) for key, value in class_1.items()}
```

Comment: also how would i find the highest value from all the scores in the list

Comment: no im trying to find the max for each seperate name

Comment: So that i can have another dictionary with highscores and names

Answer (score 1):

You can use `numpy.mean` in a generator expression to get the average for each student. You can use this paradigm in general to get other statistics.

```
>>> from numpy import mean
>>> class_1 = {'Bob':[9,5,4,3,3,4], 'John':[5,5,7,3,6], 'Andy':[7,5,6,4,5], 'Harris':[3,4,2,3,2,3,2]}
>>> class_1_average = {name: mean(values) for name, values in class_1.items()}
>>> class_1_average
{'John': 5.2000000000000002, 'Harris': 2.7142857142857144, 'Andy': 5.4000000000000004, 'Bob': 4.666666666666667}
```

Comment: is numpy in python 3 and above because its saying on mine that it the module is not there

Comment: You have to install `numpy`, it does not ship with Python

Answer (score 0):

One thing that comes to mind if you need to keep your *averages* updated "in real time" (although is probably *killing flies with nuclear weapons* and not really what you need) would be creating a custom class that inherits from the builtin [dict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict) type and extend it with an `averages` method:

```
import pprint

class MyDict(dict):
    def averages(self):
        averages = {}
        for name, score_list in self.iteritems():
            averages[name] = sum(score_list) / len(score_list)
        return averages

if __name__ == "__main__":
    class_1 = MyDict({
        'Bob': [9, 5, 4, 3, 3, 4],
        'John': [5, 5, 7, 3, 6],
        'Andy': [7, 5, 6, 4, 5],
        'Harris': [3, 4, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2]
    })

    print "class_1: %s" % pprint.pformat(class_1)
    print "class_1_averages: %s" % pprint.pformat(class_1.averages())
    print "Bob's average: %s" % pprint.pformat(class_1.averages()['Bob'])
    print "Setting Bob's scores to [1, 1, 1]"
    class_1['Bob'] = [1, 1, 1]
    print "Bob's average: %s" % pprint.pformat(class_1.averages()['Bob'])
```

That outputs:

```
class_1: {'Andy': [7, 5, 6, 4, 5],
 'Bob': [9, 5, 4, 3, 3, 4],
 'Harris': [3, 4, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2],
 'John': [5, 5, 7, 3, 6]}
class_1_averages: {'Andy': 5, 'Bob': 4, 'Harris': 2, 'John': 5}
Bob's average: 4
Setting Bob's scores to [1, 1, 1]
Bob's average: 1
```

Maybe you can use this as an idea of what Python allows you to do (which doesn't necessarily mean that you should be doing it this way) You're probably much better off with Hackaholic's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28592650/289011).