# How to work out an average from items within a dict.?

Tags: python, dictionary, average

I am new to python so a simplified explanation would be much appreciated!

As of now I have a dictionary that looks like this:

```
names = {'Bob Smith': ['5', '6', '7', '5'], 'Fred Jones': ['8', '5', '7', '5', '9'], 'James Jackson': ['5','8','8','6','5']}
```

I need to do the following:

- Take the last three items from each of the entries in the dict. e.g. 6, 7, 5  for bob smith.
- Calculate an average based upon those values. e.g. Bob smith would be 6.
- List the averages in order from highest to lowest (without the dict keys).

So far I have the following enclosed in an if statement:

```
if method == 2:
    for scores in names.items():
        score = scores[-1,-2,-3]
        average = sum(int(score)) / float(3)
        print(average)
```

I had a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28592580/working-out-an-average-of-the-values-in-a-dictionary) thread too but I am still stuck.

Can anyone give me some pointers?

Comment: One potential problem - you are storing your scores as strings, not integers. Is there a reason for that?

Comment: Sorry didn't realise that could you help me fix it? There isn't a specific reason no.

Comment: Use negative indexing. Since indexing works like `[start:stop]`, use `[-3:]` which means you want the third from last index till the end.

Comment: How can we help you if you change the question to eliminate your problem? I've rolled back Rev 3 → 2.

Answer (score 3):

`Scores[-1,-2,-3]` does not get the last three elements. It gets the element at the key `(-1,-2,-3)` in a dictionary, which will raise an error in the case of a list. `Scores[-3:]` would get the last three elements.

When getting the scores, you need to use `names.values()` instead of `names.items()`

The python string-to-integer conversions in the `int` type constructor are not smart enough to handle **lists of strings**, only **individual strings**. Using `map(int,score)` or `int(i) for i in score` would fix that.

The variable `score` is also an extremely poor choice of name for a list of elements.

Comment: That makes sense i will make amendments to my code. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Why is `score` a bad variable name? It's probably a list of game scores or something...

Comment: A better variable name would be score**s**

Answer (score 0):

```
names = {'Bob Smith': ['5', '6', '7', '5'], 'Fred Jones': ['8', '5', '7', '5', '9'], 'James Jackson': ['5','8','8','6','5']}

def avg(l):
    l = list(map(int,l))
    return sum(l[-3:])/3

avgs = []
for each in names.values():
    avgs.append(avg(each))

avgs.sort(reverse=True)
print avgs
```

Output:

```
[7, 6, 6]
```

Comment: I get the error: TypeError: 'map' object is not subscriptable

Comment: My bad dint realize youre suing python 3. Will edit my answer

Comment: @AngryManStudios - try it now

Comment: @Ietsc You never state the problem

Comment: @ppperry - you already had stated the problem which you later deleted. Usage of `map` is different in python 2 than 3

Comment: That's not what I mean. I mean that code-only answers like yours do not thee the OP what specific problem. Why is your code better than theirs?

Comment: Explained in comment what the issue was with the indexing

Answer (score 0):

In Python3.4+, there is a statistics module

```
>>> names = {'Bob Smith': ['5', '6', '7', '5'], 'Fred Jones': ['8', '5', '7', '5', '9'], 'James Jackson': ['5','8','8','6','5']}
>>> import statistics
>>> sorted((statistics.mean(map(int, x[-3:])) for x in names.values()), reverse=True)
[7.0, 6.333333333333333, 6.0]
```